# How do I fix CSRF Missmatch?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to run a request to an API I'm using via the "axios" package in my js app using expressJS.

I'm just constantly getting "CSRF token missmatch" despite the token being correct, it works using the YARC google chrome extension, but doesn't work in my app or postman.

The code I'm using is:

```
    var options = {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "https://example.com/lines/data",
        "headers": {
          "X-CSRF-TOKEN": "IZ1QTMDHl3D0HFkAPemC13 - removed some of token",
          "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
          "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
        },
        data: {
            'token': 'IZ1QTMDHl3D0HFkAPemC13 - removed some of token',
        }
    }
    request(options, function(err, response, body) {
        if(err) {
            if(err.code == "ETIMEDOUT" && err.connect == true) {
                res.status(500).json({status: "FAILED"})
                return;
            } else {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(500).json({status: "FAILED"})
                return;
            }
        }
        // var body = JSON.parse(body);

        res.send(body);
    })
```

it returns "{ "message": "CSRF token mismatch." }"

Using the following request with the chrome extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/yet-another-rest-client/ehafadccdcdedbhcbddihehiodgcddpl?hl=en) works fine and returns my json

```
{
  "method": "POST",
  "transformRequest": [
    null
  ],
  "transformResponse": [
    null
  ],
  "url": "https://example.com/lines/data",
  "headers": {
    "X-CSRF-TOKEN": "IZ1QTMDHl3D0HFkAPemC13 - removed some of token",
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
  },
  "data": "",
  "timeout": {}
}
```

- note: I'm new to all of this, so if it's really basic, my apologies.

Comment: What happens when you remove the CSRF token from the body?

Comment: @jmkmay just the same, will get the token missmatch error as far as I remember, or it might've been the 419 error which I believe is more or less the same as missmatch?

Comment: Could the server be using User Agent to generate the CSRF token? Only thing I can think of. What happens when you request a new CSRF token from your javascript runtime?